# Плавная прокрутка react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, прокрутка

Есть ли статья или готовое решения, для реализации плавной прокрутки пользователем на react ?
Различные `npm : react-smooth-scroll` или `react-smooth-scrollbar` - не очень подходят, но результат, который они дают хороший

Comment: Чем не подходят?

Comment: @Qwertiy он ломает работу react-parallax и некоторые функции react-gsap

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить ref в компонент на который необходимо прокрутить скрол и далее вызывать ref.current.scrollIntoView(). Получается примерно так:

```js
const MyComponent = ({ componentRef }) => {
  return (
    <div ref={componentRef} style={{ width: '150px' }}>
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum
      explicabo fuga quidem maxime laudantium maiores non, odit vero consectetur
      hic similique sequi itaque minima obcaecati doloribus neque repudiandae
      dolorum esse. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const ref1 = React.useRef(null);
  const ref2 = React.useRef(null);
  const ref3 = React.useRef(null);
  const ref4 = React.useRef(null);

  const buttonHandler = (ref) => {
    ref.current.scrollIntoView();
  };

  return (
    <div style={{scrollBehavior: 'smooth'}} class="container">
      <MyComponent componentRef={ref1} />
      <button onClick={() => buttonHandler(ref4)}>Go to 4</button>
      <MyComponent componentRef={ref2} />
      <button onClick={() => buttonHandler(ref3)}>Go to 3</button>
      <MyComponent componentRef={ref3} />
      <button onClick={() => buttonHandler(ref2)}>Go to 2</button>
      <MyComponent componentRef={ref4} />
      <button onClick={() => buttonHandler(ref1)}>Go to 1</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('main'))
```

```css
html, body, main, .container {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<main></main>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение по плавной прокрутке ( по нажатию ), но это не то, что мне нужно. Нужна плавная прокрутка за счёт скролла страницы, а не по нажатию кнопки

Comment: @KonstantinModin, сделал твой код запускаемым сниппетом, но менять побоялся.

Comment: @9024872139, ну так тебе надо просто сделать `html, body { scrollBehavior: smooth }` и всё.

Comment: @Qwertiy я так понимаю это в css надо вставить ? но нету такого свойства, есть только - scroll-behavior. Или это надо в код прописать ?

Comment: @9024872139, да через дефис правильно, я скопипастил из js и забыл поправить. Только прописать надо в глобальные стили.

Comment: @Qwertiy это свойство хорошо работает для якорей, но для плавного скроллинга пользователем - оно вообще не работает ((( А есть другие решения ?

Comment: @9024872139, тогда я вообще не понимаю, чего ты хочешь.

Comment: @Qwertiy если посмотришь демки, как работают react-smooth-scroll или react-smooth-scrollbar, сможешь понять, чего я хочу

Comment: @9024872139, для десктопных эта фигня вообще не нужна, а для мобильных есть `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; will-change: scroll-position;`, но надо быть осторожнее, потому что могут быть побочные эффекты на абсолютное позиционирование.